# Problem with radio button tag ruby ​on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a simple account registration and update form and I have recently entered a parameter that can have two possible choices, in my case one problem occurred:

1. Problem:

> ```
>   <div class="tag">
>       <%= f.label :ruolo %><br />
>       <%= f.radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "admin") %>
>       <%= f.label_tag(:ruolo_admin, "admin") %>
>       <%= f.radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "user")  %>
>       <%= f.label_tag(:ruolo_user, "user") %>  
>   </div>
> ```

if I leave the code like this it gives me an error like:
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#edit

undefined method `radio_button_tag 'for # <ActionView :: Helpers :: FormBuilder: 0x00007fd6fd02f478>

this is the form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l6 offset-l3">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4 class="center">Registrazione</h4>

    <br>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :ruolo %><br />
      <%= f.radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "admin") %>
      <%= f.label_tag(:ruolo_admin, "admin") %>
      <%= f.radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "user") %>
      <%= f.label_tag(:ruolo_user, "user") %>  
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Iscriviti", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn btn-devise" %>
    </div>

    <br>

  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  
  protected


  

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    @roles=Role.all
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:ruolo])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:ruolo])
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the console output. When you submit the form that works (which is working because you have the tags paired with their labels) what gets submitted for parameters. When you say "does not take the role field" do you mean that the role does not get entered into that column for the DB record? If so, your console will tell us why.

Comment: this is the output of my console: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `radio_button_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00007fbb80d0e920>
Did you mean?  radio_button):   if I try has delete "f." from all the lines, it works but the "ruolo" field is not inserted in the db

Comment: No. I want to see the web server console not just the error. And it needs to be the form that works. You are getting an error because you are trying to mix your tags and labels. The web server console will have a request and a response. Don't paste it here. Edit you question and add it there.

Comment: Also you need to show the entire form. Where is the loop that defines 'f' ?

Comment: I posted the entire content of the form

Comment: Add the HTML that the form generates and your controller code. No one can help if they have to guess at everything.

Comment: done that's okay?

Answer (score 2):

`radio_button_tag` is not an instance method of `ActionView :: Helpers :: FormBuilder`, but rather `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper`

So instead of calling it like:

```
<%= f.radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "admin") %>
```

You simply call it like:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:ruolo, "admin") %>
```

For more details on this method please check the docs:
https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

Comment: thanks for the advice, doing this does not give me more error but the form does not take the "ruolo" field